# Liquibase DiffChangelog ignores existing MySQL views

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have the following problem with Liquibase DiffChangelog operation:

I'm using Mysql 5.1, Liquibase 3.3.0 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar. I try to diff 2 databases with respectively 1 table and 1 view. If I run DiffChangelog a change log is generated that contains a changeSet with createView element although both databases contain the same view definitions.

Comment: Did you verify that both view definitions are really the same? Have you let liquibase create the view (with the existing changeset file) and then run the diff again? Also, did you check all constraints/references to the view (I think liquibase also checks those when it compares views/tables).

Comment: You can run "diff" instead of "diffChangeLog" and it will output a report of the differences rather than what it can do to try to fix the differences. That can sometimes help with the troubleshooting.

Comment: I ran "diff". The only difference between the two view definitions is the schema name. How can say Liquibase to exclude the schema name from diff? I tried "--includeSchema=false" but the generated changelog still contains the "create view" statement.

Comment: "generateChangeLog" also ignores "unsigned" on all integer types. You can file a bug report